# In JQUERY how to find that all ajax calls in a page have been completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In JQUERY how to find that all ajax calls in a page have been completed?

I want to execute a method after all the ajax call are completed.

Comment: Are _you_ making all the AJAX calls on the page (and not interested in external ones like analytics) and are all the AJAX called made with $.ajax and similar methods?

Comment: Do what ever you want to do inside the success function of ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running a number of requests and you want to know when they're all done, you're looking for `$.ajaxStop()`, which is a global event and which is "called when all AJAX requests have completed", [according to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many ajax call you have sent by **increment some variable on each call**. You can use another variable in success of ajax call to count how **many times success is called**. When both variables have same value you can assume all ajax calls are completed.

Answer (score 2):

check on this article http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2011/10/20/coordinating-multiple-ajax-requests-with-jquery-when/

This is the code from their example:

```
$.when( getTweets('austintexasgov'),
        getTweets('greenling_com'),
        getTweets('themomandpops')
      ).done(function(atxArgs, greenlingArgs, momandpopsArgs){
    var allTweets = [].concat(atxArgs[0]).concat(greenlingArgs[0]).concat(momandpopsArgs[0]);
    var sortedTweets = sortTweets(allTweets);
    showTweets(sortedTweets);
      });

var getTweets = function(user){
    var url='http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/' + user + '.json';
    return $.get(url, {count:5}, null, 'jsonp');
}
```

Worked perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

To monitor tasks like this, you can always build a state machine.  On each ajax call, add a `beforeSend()` callback and a `complete()` callback to update state to some state machine.  The `completed` method on your state machine will conditionally execute your code if the count is at 0.

Note.... this will ONLY work if there are ajax calls with overlapping execution (running in parallel).  If you have ajax calls running in serial, your state machine will execute each time all **active** ajax calls are in a completed state.

To work correctly with serial ajax calls, you would have to know in advance how many ajax calls you're going to make, and test against that number.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
}).beforeSend(function() {
    ajaxState.started();
}).complete(function() {
    ajaxState.completed();
});

var ajaxState = {
    active: 0,
    started: function() {
        ajaxState.active++;
    },
    completed: function() {
        ajaxState.active--;
        if (!ajaxState.active) ajaxState.onComplete();
    },
    onComplete: function() {
        // Your code here.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you call a method in the last Ajax method? There is no way to know if you've got any Ajax call made by a button for example that will be generated dynamically or whatever.

If you are sure about your last Ajax call, call a method on success.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    type: "POST",
    data: {id : menuId},
}).done(function() {
    callMethod();
});
```